# Angular2 http.post and undefined req.body

Tags: json, node.js, http, post, angular

I have a problem with receiving json from http.post. Let's make it clear a bit:
This is my component file:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Headers} from 'angular2/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'login-form',
  template: `
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <button type="submit">Wyslij</button>
    </form>
  `
})

export class LoginFormComponent {
  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  onSubmit() {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    var data = JSON.stringify({
      login: "zupa",
    });

    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/send', data, {headers: headers})
    .subscribe();
  }
}
```

My server.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render("index.html", {title: 'Aplikacja'});
});

app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log("Starting at localhost:8080");
});

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see, this is a standard generated by express module server file.

This is content of my "routes" file.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index.html', {title: 'Infam'});
});

router.post('/send', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Received data: " + req.body.login);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The server returns a message to me: "Received data: **undefined**" and I have no idea why the req.body.login is undefined. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

PS: The same is when I use

```
"login": "zupa"
```

instead of

```
login: "zupa"
```

Comment: what do you get when you log out just req.body on the server side.

Comment: please post the content of 'req'

Comment: Hey, in that case I have `[object Object]`. When I use `console.log("Received data: " JSON.stringify(req.body))` i have `{"{\"login\":\"zupa\"}":""}` so it looks like there is something wrong with parsing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should set the appropriate headers since you are using JSON.

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Exacly! I was using this headers type in my jquery but here I set what was typed in a lot of tutorials where they also was sending json files (so I was confused a bit). By the way, sometimes I forget to use my own brain :P Thank you!